# jQuery ajax call doesn't seem to do anything at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I am having a problem with making an ajax call in jQuery. Having done this a million times, I know I am missing something really silly here. Here is my javascript code for making the ajax call:

```
   function editEmployee(id) {
       $('#<%= imgNewEmployeeWait.ClientID %>').hide();
       $('#divAddNewEmployeeDialog input[type=text]').val('');
       $('#divAddNewEmployeeDialog select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
       $('#divAddNewEmployeeDialog').dialog('open');
       $('#createEditEmployeeId').text(id);
       var inputEmp = {};
       inputEmp.id = id;
       var jsonInputEmp = JSON.stringify(inputEmp);
       debugger;
       alert('Before Ajax Call!');
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Configuration.aspx/GetEmployee",
           data: jsonInputEmp,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (msg) {
               alert('success');
           },
           error: function (msg) {
               alert('failure');
           }
       });
   }
```

Here is my CS code that is trying to be called:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        var employee = new Employee(id);

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

When I try to run this, I do get the alert that says `Before Ajax Call!`. However, I never get an alert back that says `success` or an alert that says `failure`. I did go into my CS code and put a breakpoint on the `GetEmployee` method. The breakpoint did hit, so I know jQuery is successfully calling the method. I stepped through the method and it executed just fine with no errors. I can only assume the error is happening when the jQuery ajax call is returning from the call.

Also, I looked in my event logs just to make sure there wasn't an ASPX error occurring. There is no error in the logs. I also looked at the console. There are no script errors. Anyone have any ideas what I am missing here?

`

Comment: Try using "console.log(msg); " instead of alert success/failure and look in the browser console log (control shift J on chrome, but all recent browsers have a log) to see if msg is logged. If it shows up in the log, you can click on msg and expand it and see what it says.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see if request actually goes out and what is coming back. If using Chrome set "when thrown" for exception handling. Also consider to wrap `$.ajax` into try/catch to know if it fails directly/see what is failing (not your case now).

Comment: Isn't the ajax property `dataType`, not `contentType`?

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks to everyone's comments. My Employee Class had a property that goes out and gets data from my database. When I called SerializeObject on it, it tried to pull all this data and serialize it into JSON. I wound up creating a container class for it that contains just the properties I really need. It works fine now. Thanks for all the comments! The comments helped me to figure out what was going on.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If you or Paul want to make an answer out of your comment, I'll accept it

Comment: @icemanind:Since you found the solution, post a answer yourself and accept it or delete the question. Then others won't waste their time on this :)

Comment: Agree with Chamika - my suggestion can't be "answer" to the question. It is still unclear what exactly was causing the problem (huge amount of data, non-serializable result, something else). Or if you want you can change question into "how to investigate...." so our comments could be considered answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
function editEmployee(id) {
   $('#<%= imgNewEmployeeWait.ClientID %>').hide();
   $('#divAddNewEmployeeDialog input[type=text]').val('');
   $('#divAddNewEmployeeDialog select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
   $('#divAddNewEmployeeDialog').dialog('open');
   $('#createEditEmployeeId').text(id);
   //var inputEmp = {};
  // inputEmp.id = id;
  // var jsonInputEmp = JSON.stringify(inputEmp);
   //debugger;
   alert('Before Ajax Call!');
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Configuration.aspx/GetEmployee",
       data: {id: id},
      // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      // dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
           alert('success');
       },
       error: function (msg) {
           alert('failure');
       }
   });   }
```

Answer (score 0):

if ajax call doesnot goes inside the success function then the problem is with your dataformat in CS code . the return data must not be in a proper JSON format . you should be getting "500" Error i guess.

**Try returning it in a proper JSON format.**